# step into .framework code in xcode

Tags: xcode, xcode4, gdb

I have some libraries that are linked as .framework files in XCode 4.  I cannot view the source code if I step into the classes from these libraries, or set breakpoints in it : I can view the information in the call stack, but XCode doesn't figure out where the corresponding source is.

I can only get this to work if I set the libraries up instead as .a libraries that get built from the source, and link to those instead.  This is a big hassle (nobody else working on this project has it set up that way and the .xcodeproj file is in source control).

Is there any way I can link against a .framework and be able to step into the source code and set breakpoints inside it?

Answer (score 0):

You need to have both th project for the framework as well as the project for the code using it.

Make sure you have both projects open and your app project has a dependency on the framework project.

At this point you should be able to hit breakpoints set in the framework while debugging the app.

Answer (score 0):

A simple but cumbersome way to step into framework code is to add a symbolic breakpoint for the symbol that you want to step in to.

- In Xcode, Press Cmd+8 to enter the breakpoint navigator
- Hit the bottom-left + sign
- Select Symbolic breakpoint...
- Under 'Symbol' fill in the method that needs to be explored, eg: `sendAccessibilityRequestAsync:completionQueue:completionHandler:`
- Optionally, limit the scope of the breakpoint by setting the Module that contains the code to step into

[image]

Run the code, when the framework method is called, lldb will break at the method entry point.